# Getting JSON values

Tags: javascript, json

So I need to get the hash the `prev_out` address and value and also the `out` address.
But I am having some issues, I am able to get the hash but not any other sub-values.

```
{
"op": "utx",
"x": {
    "hash": "f6c51463ea867ce58588fec2a77e9056046657b984fd28b1482912cdadd16374",
    "ver": 1,
    "vin_sz": 4,
    "vout_sz": 2,
    "lock_time": "Unavailable",
    "size": 796,
    "relayed_by": "209.15.238.250",
    "tx_index": 3187820,
    "time": 1331300839,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "prev_out": {
                "value": 10000000,
                "type": 0,
                "addr": "12JSirdrJnQ8QWUaGZGiBPBYD19LxSPXho"
            }
        }
    ],
    "out": [
        {
            "value": 2800000000,
            "type": 0,
            "addr": "1FzzMfNt46cBeS41r6WHDH1iqxSyzmxChw"
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I go about getting these?

Comment: You're lazy to write clearly as your name suggests ! :v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as (assume your json wrapped in `json` object):

```
var hash     = json.x.hash;
var prev_out = json.x.inputs[0].prev_out.addr;
var out      = json.x.out[0].addr
```

What's is the problem? You are using `javascript` right? If you are using other language like `Scala` or anything, that is make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `var` is the variable that contains this object, to get the `prev_out` address:

```
var.x.inputs[0].prev_out.addr
```

To get the `out` address:

```
var.x.out[0].addr
```

You use `.property` to access an object property, and `[index]` to access an array element. Objects are surrounded by `{}`, arrays are surrounded by `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

assume your json is stored in `json` object then :

```
for(key in json.x.inputs){
   for(key1 in json.x.inputs[key].prev_out){
       console.log('key1:',key1);
       console.log('value:',json.x.inputs[key].prev_out[key1]);
   }
}
```